# Einstein Content Selection - Email Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have been reading through [Einstien Content Selection](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_content_selection.htm&type=5), and understand it will be a beneficial product if integrated with the company website and then can send the personalised email to customers.

However, I want to check if someone has just used it for the email sends? E.g. If I send a weekly newsletter to around 1 million subscribers, and wish to use Einstein Content Selection for this monthly send, will it be beneficial? Because I will be changing the content areas every month, but still with Einstien Content selection I will update the existing content areas used by Einstien. in that way Einstien will able to send the personalised content to every subscriber afer 30 days of learning.

Please let me know your thoughts if this is a fair use case for Einstein Content Selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm, Einstein Content Selection is specific to image assets (it's name is somewhat misleading, I think it should be named 'Einstein Image Selection'). The model analyses the image assets available for Subscribers, according to the defined business rules and metadata*, and selects the image content that is (a) best for each Subscriber, (b) most popular content and (c) content that has a high likelihood to click.

In your scenario (sending one newsletter email to 1m Subscribers), Einstein will choose images at **open-time**, based on the Subscriber engagement of your audience.

You don't need to wait 30 days after enabling this feature (perhaps you are thinking of Einstein Email & Web Recommendations).

**Note that using consumer metadata and business rules is entirely optional, you can use Einstein Content Selection just with the asset class and start/end dates.*